# How can I force a table made using the CSS display: table to fit within a minimum height?

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I am using display: table, display: table-row and display: table-cell.  I have large number of rows in a table and I am using the AngularJS ng-repeat to populate these.  Here's an example with just two rows but in practice I have may more and I need these to all fit within the 10rem height.

```
<div style=height: 10rem>
 <div style="display: table">
  <div style="display: table-row">
      <div style="display: table-cell">
      xxx
      </div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">
      xxx
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row">
      <div style="display: table-cell">
      xxx
      </div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">
      xxx
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to limit the height of the table (grid) and have a scroll bar on the right. However whatever I do it does not seem to force the table to fit within a `<div>` with a height defined.

Can anyone give me any advice on how I can limit the table height and have a vertical and horizontal scroll bar appear.

Comment: Maybe try `overflow: scroll;` in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow-x: scroll` (or `auto`) to the container. (The one with height 10rem.) And `overflow-x: visible`  to the table element itself.

Addition: You forgot the quotation marks in the first line:

```
<div style="height: 10rem">
```